# PowerShell - Activate Service Plan License for all Users of one Region

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, licensing

In Office 365 licenses and service plans can be set by PowerShell. 
There are several licenses available such as "**ENTERPRISEPACK**" which is the code for "**Office 365 Enterprise E3**".

Within the enabled license of Office 365 Enterprise E3 there are several Service Plans for included products like "**SharePoint Online**".

**I need to enable the license "ENTERPRISEPACK" for all users of the region "US" and "DE". In addition I need to activate Service Plan "SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE" (SharePoint Online (Part 2) for all of this users.**

Most of them still have "ENTERPRISEPACK" enabled but do not have service pack SharePoint Online enabled.

Anyone knows how to solve this by PowerShell.

I can connect to O365 and read available Service Plans with this commandlets.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-MsolService
Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuPartNumber -eq “ENTERPRISEPACK”} | ForEach-Object {$_.ServiceStatus}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out the solution for this.

First connect to Office365 via PowerShell as mentioned above.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-MsolService
```

Now set the license options you want to set. In this case the whole Office 365 E3 plan is set with all sub licenses except for ToDo, Forms, Stream, Flow and PowerApps.

```
$licensopt =New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId <tenant>:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans BPOS_S_TODO_2,FORMS_PLAN_E3,STREAM_O365_E3,FLOW_O365_P2,POWERAPPS_O365_P2
```

Then be aware to remove the given E3 plans from this users before you set them with exception of the mentioned sub licenses above.

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where{$_.UsageLocation -eq "DE" -and $_.UserPrincipalName -like "*@SomeDomain.de"} |foreach{set-msoluserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "<tenant>:ENTERPRISEPACK" }
```

Now you can give them the license without Stream, Flow and other stuff as shown above.

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where{$_.UsageLocation -eq "DE" -and $_.UserPrincipalName -like "*@SomeDomain.de"} |foreach{set-msoluserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "<tenant>:ENTERPRISEPACK" -LicenseOptions $licensopt }
```

This works fine as tested in our tenant. Please replace  with your tenant identifier.